# Add billing and shipping address to register form Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to add billing ask user for billing and shipping address when register (in registration form) with a checkbox (shipping address is same).
I searched on internet, but I did not found the solution that work for me.
I tried to set **setShowAddressFields** to true, but does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add these lines in `Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml`:

```
<action method="setShowAddressFields">
       <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
</action>
```